# how to point webhook to front end

Tags: node.js, express, webhooks

I have a webhook being fired when an event occurs. It successfully hits my backend server.

My frontend is localhost:3000

My backend is localhost:5000

My backend route looks like so

```
   app.get('/webhook', (req, res) => {
    console.log("webhoook fired")});
        res.json({message: "webHook response"}) // How can I point this to front end? 
}
```

My Question is, My webhook is being fired by a 3rd party that sends a get request to my backend. How I am I able to send a response to my front end within this function? does the res just go back to the 3rd party?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does the res just go back to the 3rd party?

Yes, because they made a request to your server and if required, you can respond to them.

> How am I able to send a response to my front end within this function?

If you want to update data in the front-end once your server received data from 3rd-party webhooks, in most cases, you need to use WebSockets to accomplish that. In short, WebSockets allow real-time communication between server and client by keeping a continuous connection between each other. You can look at [native WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket) first, and also check out available libraries such as [socket.io](https://socket.io/) or [ws](https://github.com/websockets/ws) :)

Comment: So could I have a webhook hit the backend and trigger an emit function with a websocket to front end? Does that make sense?

Comment: I didn't understand your example, but you can have a web socket connection between the front-end and back-end. Once your API for webhooks on the back-end is called, you can send data to the front-end via web sockets.